# Regular Expression returns null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am kinda stumped, the regular expression found here works: https://regex101.com/r/rD5nP9/1

It finds all of the matches, but when I put it in my code, I get `null` and I am not sure why.

```
var value = "name == 'Bob'";

var regex = new RegExp('(.+?)\s(.+?)\s(.+)');

var matches = value.match(regex); // returns null
regex.exec(value); // returns null
```

What I am trying to get is an array that looks like this:

```
["name", "==", "'Bob'"]
```

But for some reason the code isn't finding it, but it works on http://regex101.com and I get a list of matching items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslash or otherwise it would treat `\s` as an escape sequence.

```
var regex = new RegExp("(.+?)\\s(.+?)\\s(.+)");
```

or

Use forward slashes as regex delimiters.

```
var regex = /(.+?)\s(.+?)\s(.+)/;
```

Comment: Well I feel stupid now I knew that. Not sure why I missed that.